# SSRS: Trouble applying custom expression to Vertical Axis Chart Label

Tags: reporting-services, expression, label

Using visual studio BI dev studio 2008.

I have a chart that has a Y axis of numbers ranging from 0 to about 1500 (Values), an x axis of dates (Category Group).  The Y-axis numbers are integers representing minutes.

I want to convert the Y-Axis of minutes to hh:mm form and I thought it would be simple to write a custom function to do so. However, after going to Vertical Axis Properties -> Number -> Custom format, I am finding that the custom expression will **not** calculate most expressions that I give it.

For example, I have tried

```
=(Fields!RealRunTimeMin.Value) * 2
=(Fields!RealRunTimeMin.Value) + 1000
```

But when I go to Preview the report, the y-Axis is in the same range (0 to 1500) rather than displaying 0-3000.

I have also tried

```
=CInt(Fields!RealRunTimeMin.Value) + 1000
```

But the chart remains unchanged.  The only thing I seem able to do is convert the number to a string.

Any idea on what I am doing wrong? Note: I'm not asking for the logic to format to hh:mm, but rather I am asking why all attempts to maniuplate numbers in SSRS's axis labels seem to be defeating me.

Thanks in advance,

T

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expressions are not supported with this set of functionality.  I do realize that the UI suggests that it is,  but that is a bug in the current product.  You will need to perform the calculations at either the query or dataset level.